# How to lock function from multiple ajax requests in short period of time without threads

Tags: python, django, locking, xmlhttprequest, facebook-like

I'm dealing with the problem I've seen some people also struggling. I need some functionality based on Facebook like buttons events. So I catch the event of clicking button and on it call my function with ajax. But on each single click my function is called multiple times, varying from 3 to 8. Problem is that this function creates models that ought to be unique, and because of the instant multiple call - I get multiple objects.
How to prevent this ? I've tried setting global var, but without any luck :

```
def send_submission(request):
    global BLOCKED

    if BLOCKED == 0:
        logging.debug("should be locked")
        BLOCKED = 1

        (... do something...)

        BLOCKED = 0

    html = render_page(request)
    ajax = simplejson.dumps({
        "html": html
    }, cls=LazyEncoder)
    return HttpResponse(ajax, mimetype='application/javascript')
```

And the js grabbing the call:

```
    FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function(href, widget) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/submissions/add",
            data: "href="+href+"&ip={{ IP_ADDRESS }}", 
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data){
                $("#submissions").html(data["html"])
            }
        });
        return false;       
    });
```

I've tried locking it with js, but it does not work either.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {

        var maxAjaxCallAllowed=1;
        var openAjaxCalls = new Array();

        function insertHtml(data){
            openAjaxCalls.pop();
            $(".list-submissions").html(data["html"])
        }

        FB.init({appId: '161771113844567', status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true});

        FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function(href, widget) {
            alert("glos");
            if(openAjaxCalls.length < maxAjaxCallAllowed){
                openAjaxCalls.push(1);
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "{% url register_vote %}",
                    data: "href="+href+"&ip={{ IP_ADDRESS }}", 
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function(data){
                        insertHtml(data);
                    }
                });
            }
            else{
                alert('Server call not possible at this time');
            }                              
        });
    };
    (function() {
    var e = document.createElement('script');
    e.type = 'text/javascript';
    e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
    e.async = true;
    document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
    }());
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am getting your issue correct, I think you should define a global variable in javascript. Say you have a global variable `busy` which should be set once a request is sent and unset when the request is completed.

Before every request you should check whether the variable is set and if its set do not send the request again.